# Visual Studio on corporate computer

Tags: asp.net, windows, visual-studio

I am looking to pick up ASP.NET on my corporate computer, and am wondering if I will lose any control/ functionality when running visual studio (either express or professional) as simply a "user" (U:). Will I need an administrator in any common case through the learning and development process?

Answer (score 1):

This quote is on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165100%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Most features and tasks can be completed without administrator
>   permissions. If an operation does require elevated permissions, a
>   message box will appear. In these instances, you may be prompted to
>   restart Visual Studio 2008 with administrator permission to complete
>   the task.

However, because there are times you need admin rights - e.g. Click-Once Deployment - I would always recommend it. Or rather demand it!

Also, if you're building websites then access to IIS, for example, is going to make your life a lot easier. And IIS management without admin rights is going to be a problem.

Comment: See I believe I attempted this a year ago and was in fact having trouble setting up IIS (I was using web express edition).

Comment: You don't have to use IIS for web development but in general admin rights will help.

Comment: What are my alternatives?

Comment: Use IIS Express, which never needs admin.

Comment: Agreed, IIS Express is good to use. The general point, that all developers should have admin rights on their machine, remains.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does not need administrative privileges for general use.

Comment: Are there any disadvantages of any sort?